# how can i get a object with email and password when i click submit button

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to get an object `{email:"abc@gmail.com",password:"1234"}` when the user press the submit button

i have tried to make a const in the handleChange to dave that value in the but i am only getting one value at a time.

```
this.state = {
  is_authenticated: false,
  application_status_modal_visible: false,
  login_data: []
};

handleChange = event => {
  const { login_data } = this.state;
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  const obj = { ...obj };
  obj[name] = value;
  console.log(obj);
  this.setState({ login_data: [...login_data, obj] });
};

handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log(this.state.login_data);
};

modalCancel = () => {
  this.setState({ application_status_modal_visible: false });
};

<Modal
  title="Login"
  visible={application_status_modal_visible}
  onOk={this.handleSubmit}
  onCancel={this.modalCancel}
>
  <Form>
    <FormItem>
      <Input
        prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
        placeholder="Email"
        name={"email"}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem>
      <Input
        prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        name={"password"}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </FormItem>
  </Form>
</Modal>;
...
```

i am expecting this result `{email:"sasas@gmail.com",password:"121212"}`

Comment: Just like the `input` has on `onChange` the `form` should have on `onSubmit`... Here are the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `state`, you have to use immutable operations. With nested objects this can be a bit tricky without using a custom library. You should also avoid accessing `this.state` before updating state. Instead, use an update function:

```
handleChange = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const { login_data } = prevState;
    return { // returning a change object
      login_data: {
        ...login_data,  // copy the original
        [name]: value // overwrite value
      }
    };
  });
};
```

Also note that you should initialize `login_data` as `{}` not `[]`. It's an object, not an array.

However, the ideal solution is not to use nested objects at all unless your `state` gets more complicated:

```
this.state = {
  is_authenticated: false,
  application_status_modal_visible: false
  email: "",
  password: ""
};

handleChange = event => {  
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
     [name]: value
  });
};

handleSubmit = () => {
  const { email, password } = this.state;
  const loginData = { email, password };
  console.log(loginData);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
this.state = {
  is_authenticated: false,
  application_status_modal_visible: false,
  login_data: {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }
}

handleChange = (event) => {
  const login_data = { ...this.state.login_data };
  const { name, value } = event.target;

  login_data[name] = value;
  this.setState({ login_data });
};
```

Comment: it gives me an error but if replace the const with let it will work

Comment: @DeepankarSingh Have you tried? There is no error check this https://codesandbox.io/s/5z1r652864